# How to calculate number of duplicates in a list of numpy arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have a list of arrays (permutations) that I need to clean up.
This is how my current list looks like:

```
>>>permutations
[array([1, 2, 6, 7]),
 array([1, 2, 6, 7]),
 array([1, 2, 6, 7]),
 array([1, 2, 3, 8]),
 array([1, 2, 3, 8]),
 array([1, 2, 3, 8]),
 array([2, 3, 4, 9]),
 array([2, 3, 4, 9]),
 array([2, 3, 4, 9]),
 array([ 3,  4,  5, 10]),
 array([ 3,  4,  5, 10]),
 array([ 3,  4,  5, 10]),
 array([ 4,  5,  6, 11]),
 array([ 4,  5,  6, 11]),
 array([ 4,  5,  6, 11]),
 array([ 1,  5,  6, 12]),
 array([ 1,  5,  6, 12]),
 array([ 1,  5,  6, 12])]
```

What I want:

```
>>>neat_perm
[(array([1, 2, 6, 7]),3), 
(array([1, 2, 3, 8]),3),
(array([2, 3, 4, 9]),3)
(array([3, 4, 5, 10]), 3),
(array([4, 5, 6, 11]), 3),
(array([1, 5, 6, 12]), 3)]
```

What I want to do, is to create a list of tuples, where the first element of the tuple is the array, and the second element of the tuple is the number of times it was repeated in `permutations`.

The straightforward, brute force method is to do the `O(n^2)` np.array_equal over the array to ensure there are no repeats. The problem is the algorithmic complexity. `list(set(permutations))`, `permutations.count()` does not work as np arrays are not hashable.

I would appreciate any advice you have for me, to get this more efficient, in terms of lines of code required, or time/memory complexity!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One solution is to use `np.unique()` with `return_counts = True`, and zip the resulting unique arrays and their counts:

```
from numpy import array
import numpy as np

permutations = [array([1, 2, 6, 7]),
         array([1, 2, 6, 7]),
         array([1, 2, 6, 7]),
         array([1, 2, 3, 8]),
         array([1, 2, 3, 8]),
         array([1, 2, 3, 8]),
         array([2, 3, 4, 9]),
         array([2, 3, 4, 9]),
         array([2, 3, 4, 9]),
         array([ 3,  4,  5, 10]),
         array([ 3,  4,  5, 10]),
         array([ 3,  4,  5, 10]),
         array([ 4,  5,  6, 11]),
         array([ 4,  5,  6, 11]),
         array([ 4,  5,  6, 11]),
         array([ 1,  5,  6, 12]),
         array([ 1,  5,  6, 12]),
         array([ 1,  5,  6, 12])]


>>> list(zip(*np.unique(permutations, return_counts = True, axis = 0)))

[(array([1, 2, 3, 8]), 3),
 (array([1, 2, 6, 7]), 3),
 (array([ 1,  5,  6, 12]), 3),
 (array([2, 3, 4, 9]), 3),
 (array([ 3,  4,  5, 10]), 3),
 (array([ 4,  5,  6, 11]), 3)]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @sacuL! what is the "*" behind np.unique do?

Comment: `np.unique` with `return_counts = True` returns a tuple of the arrays and their counts, so the `*` operator unpacks it into two separate arrays, which can then be zipped together